# how do i get usb_hid on micropython

Tags: micropython, adafruit-circuitpython, usb-hid

So there is a module named usb_hid on CircuitPython but its not on MicroPython. Is there a way to get usb_hid on MicroPython?

It isnt in the lib folder of CircuitPython. I even tried displaying all the modules in MicroPython but usb_hid wasnt there. Can anybody tell me how to import it in MicroPython?

Comment: Seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164310/i-cant-find-the-pip-of-this-library-usb-hid) question may give you some more insight on this topic

Comment: MicroPython does not currently support USB HID (as at Sept 2023), you will need to use CircuitPython.